# OpenCV is getting slow in Raspberry pi 4, 8gb

Tags: opencv, arm, computer-vision

Here is have made a project attendance system, for which I have trained a model and used the .h5 file to make the real time Prediction using opencv.
so if the person face is detected then his name and timing will get registered in .txt file, so everything is working as expected but when am running the code in Pi4, the video is lagging a lot.
which is kind of disheartening for me, as this was my personal project which I worked
really hard on. any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Did you know that arm is big endian? Are you storing values in the .h5 as little endian? If so there may be computing power wasted reading it out.  Also don't forget to try different compiler optimizations.

Comment: Your title said that it is getting slow on the Pi 4. This implies, in English, that it was faster on the Pi 4, at one time. Could you explain how OpenCV is getting slower?